# Using pdo in php with stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a simple stored procedure in MySQL database:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`vidhu`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(var_datain TEXT)
BEGIN
    SELECT var_datain;
END
```

When calling this procedure in mysql-workbench it returns the data I put in:

[image: Screenshot form mysql work bench]

Now when I call it from PHP using *pdo* I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:/apache......(3rd line)
```

Here is my php code:

```
$db = new PDO(DSN, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL test(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, 'hai!', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rs = $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: Which line? I don't see anything being passed by reference

Comment: the line which has $stmt->bindParam(1, 'hai!', PDO::PARAM_STR);

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

When you use bindParam, it binds the variable provided to the parameter, not the value of the variable.

So, if you do:

```
$x = 5;
$stmt->bindParam(1, $x, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$x = 6;
$stmt->execute(); //executes with 6 instead of 5
```

It's actually executed with 6 rather than 5.  To do this, the method must have a reference to the variable.  You cannot have a reference to a literal, so this means that bindParam cannot be used with literals (or anything you can't have a reference to).

```
$x = 5;
$stmt->bindValue(1, $x, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$x = 6;
$stmt->execute(); //executes with 5 instead of 6
```

Then:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
//invalid because there's no way to pass a literal 1 by reference
$stmt->bindValue(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//valid
```

Answer (score -1):

The `bindParam` function accepts only values variables, That's why parameter two `hai` which is not a variable `cannot be passed`.
So it is not necessary the bindValue, but using the bindParam correctly.
Example: when using bindParam:
From your snippet.

```
$a = "hai";
$db = new PDO(DSN, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL test(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(s, $a, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rs = $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result[0];
```

This Should solve your problem and not the answer above.

Answer (score -6):

The following code works for calling without prepare statement!

```
$query="CALL store_procedure_name(@a)";
$conn->query($query);

$query="SELECT @a as outvar;";
$result = $conn->query($query);
foreach ($result as $x)
{
    $res=$x['outvar'];
}

echo $res;
```